# Issues with MID(text, start_num, num_chars) when changing rows

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have created simple test, because I want to create pattern for fast inserting and separating number that is inserted in one place, but when I change row in **I3** cell, I want number bellow "Whole number" in **I6** cell to be set to zero.

Also I want row **6** to remain intact from column **A** to **E**.

Next number inserted inside **I6** I want to be separated and placed in row **7** (from column **A** to **E**) when I change row on **I3** to number 7. Look at the picture I attached. Is there a way to implement this?

[image]

Comment: I believe you need vba to do that, if you want to use only formula; it will not work because the link to a cell remain static in formulas, you can only link it with one cell at a time. the cell to be linked can be made dynamic but it will always be one cell.

Comment: I've added excel-vba to tags, because I have no idea what to do with vba. Hopefully some expert will reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this function in VBA editor in the sheet where your data is present
For example if your data is in Sheet1 paste this function in Sheet1 of VBA
editor

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    If (Target.Address = "$I$6") Then

        row_num = Range("I3").Value

        If Not IsNumeric(row_num) Then Exit Sub
        If (row_num < 6) Then Exit Sub

        number_value = Target.Value

        If Not IsNumeric(number_value) Then Exit Sub
        If (number_value < 10000 Or number_value > 99999) Then Exit Sub


        Range("A" & row_num).Value = Mid(number_value, 1, 1)
        Range("B" & row_num).Value = Mid(number_value, 2, 1)
        Range("C" & row_num).Value = Mid(number_value, 3, 1)
        Range("D" & row_num).Value = Mid(number_value, 4, 1)
        Range("E" & row_num).Value = Mid(number_value, 5, 1)

    End If


    If (Target.Address = "$I$3") Then
        Range("I6").Value = 0
    End If

End Sub
```

Double click Sheet name and paste the function

[image]

Comment: Thanks, I will try and come up with results